# android studio canary 4.0, where to see the "Live updates" in Layout Inspector

Tags: android-studio

Installed android studio canary 4.0, but where to see the "Live updates" in Layout Inspector as in the copied screenshot (in my installed one there is no such checkBox?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Open `Settings` windows from `File` menu, Click `Experimental`
  settings, you can able to view the menu '`Enable Live Layout Inspector`'. Enable the checkbox and Apply the settings.
- you can able to view the Layout Inspector window in ***bottom right*** of
  Android studio prefer to Event Log window.
- At the top of Layout Inspector window, you have the `Live updates` control.

[image: Layout Inspector Enable].

Answer (score 0):

You have to opt into it since its currently experimental. In android studio go to Preferences > Experimental > Layout Inspector, and enable live layout inspector. Then restart studio and you should see a Layout Inspector tab on the bottom right of studio.